# Plantuml Rendering Differences Online and Locally

Tags: graphviz, plantuml

Using [plantuml's online renderer](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/DOz12i8m44NtSufFUmkXKXJSILrq9ovgCzX0cgb9YgZqxYPj_8ial9VvCBKFdGlpQ2ZeO9Y0ayYXSyHMRQGtCYiSr_DBLXIZE7Vze2qNAE-i7nmvi9hcqg9yip7omfKGqqn1Z_h33i0ARjjZITT2Ms4hhX_-WqIf9QQgzjbW1yT-4kkPCaao_qloERCFLBDLSPSV), consider the following diagram:

[image]

specified by the following code:

```
@startuml
title
  FooBar
endtitle
cloud Cloud {
node "Machine" #beige {
  node OPT #yellow [
    Optimizer   
    ]   
  }   
}

node Torch #yellow

OPT    ==> Torch  : response
Torch  ==> OPT    : request
@enduml
```

However, when I render the exact same code (copy-pasted) on my local machine, I get a scrunchy, ugly, unacceptable rendering:

```
$ cat > hairball.txt   
 <<< paste the above text >>>
$ plantuml hairball.txt 
$ xdg-open hairball.png
```

[image]

I have the latest versions of dot and plantuml on my ubuntu machine:

```
$ dot -V
dot - graphviz version 2.40.1 (20161225.0304)
$ plantuml -v
(0.000 - 1008 Mo) 1000 Mo - PlantUML Version 1.2019.05
```

I'm out of ideas about how to diagnose and fix this and would be grateful for help.

Comment: I confirm the same _bad rendering_ on Debian/Buster/Stable_ :
```shell
$ dot -V
dot - graphviz version 2.40.1 (20161225.0304)
$ java -jar ~/.local/bin/plantuml.jar -v
(0.000 - 124 Mo) 117 Mo - PlantUML Version 1.2019.04
(0.009 - 124 Mo) 117 Mo - GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless() false
(0.009 - 124 Mo) 117 Mo - Forcing resource load on OpenJdk
(0.124 - 124 Mo) 112 Mo - Found 0 files
$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.3 2019-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.3+7-post-Debian-5)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.3+7-post-Debian-5, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 1):

how about:

1. [download PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/)
2. Install Plugins: PlantUML integration

   - Settings → Plugins → Search "PlantUML integration" → Install
     [image]
3. Pycharm → Settings → Other Settings → PlantUML → "Graphviz doe executable: `your dot.exe path`"

   [image]
4. test.puml

   [image]

It looks fine.

Comment: It seem that is an environement/OS setting issue. Not sure `PyCharm` answered the question…